# SQL, how do I convert to logic ('not in' to 'not exists')

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
Delete From StudentTb Where StudentType in (1, 2) and StudentI not in
(
    Select lg.StudentI From StudentLog lg
)
```

I tried to changed the above code to the following... But, I am not sure if it is correct or not.

```
Delete From StudentTb Where StudentType in (1, 2) 
    and Not Exists 
    (
        Select 'x' 
        From StudentLog lg                          
        Where StudentI= lg.StudentI
    )
```

Can anyone please help me?

Comment: How are you not sure? Did you try executing it..? If you're worried about deleting try selecting first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in and not exists do not always have the same meaning.   I assume you want to convert because "not in" tends to be slow.  Here is another way where the logic will always match.

```
Delete From StudentTb 
Where StudentType in (1, 2) 
and StudentI in
(
select StudentI
from StudentTb
except 
Select StudentI From StudentLog    
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. So, it's my understanding that 'except' would be faster enough than 'not in', and try not to use 'not exists' because it sometimes fail?

Comment: Except will be faster than not in.  Use not exists when it is appropriate for what you are attempting.

Answer (score 2):

```
Delete From StudentTb  s
Where StudentType in (1, 2) 
and Not Exists 
(
    Select *
    From StudentLog                          
    Where StudentI = s.StudentI
)
```

In a subquery, unqualified references to columns(which do not specify table name or alias) are first assumed to be in the table referenced in the subquery itself, not in other tables in the outer query.  So, in your sql syntax, both sides of the predicate `Where StudentI = lg.StudentI` are the same column in the `StudentLog` subquery table.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Now, I see why my code didn't work! I will be very careful when I use subquery. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

All you did wrong is not specifying the right alias in the subquery:

```
Delete From StudentTb Where StudentType in (1, 2) 
    and Not Exists 
    (
        Select 'x' 
        From StudentLog lg                          
        Where StudentTb.StudentI= lg.StudentI
    )
```

Note - the columns in the select statement doesn't affect the final outcome, but it's still preferred to write `*` instead of `'x'`

Comment: Thank you for the response. So the difference between your answer and mine is StudentTb.StudentI??